# Magento one page login not working

Tags: magento, authentication, onepage-checkout

currently i am working with a magento shopping site.I am newbie to magento. When i tried to login via one page both login and create button are disabled.
Default login and create account working fine.I have added

```
 <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

please help me to solve the problem.Thanks in advance.

please check this link
http://qwertykart.com/checkout/onepage/

Answer (score 1):

Check your one page checkout setting if register is not enabled.

if there is no setting for this, then Install this Extension to see exact .phtml file, where you need to edit.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html

After setup, you can get your template path by adding tp=1&code=1 in the url.
(You have to save code value in magento backend)

I see your Register button having "disabled"=disabled attribute. Try to remove that. After removing that you will be able to register.

Do it for other buttons as well.